# Code working awhile ago then "java.util.InputMismatchException"

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, inputmismatchexception

Take it easy, I'm self-taught and am pretty new to all this.
So I was trying to write an Address Book. everything was working fine, no errors, no exceptions. Saved the project, switched of my laptop, went for lunch. Came back, tried to run the code, received an error.

Based on the exception I know it has something to do with my Scanner. 
The Exception highlighted

```
int phone = inFile.nextInt()
```

As the problem. But I cant figure out what's wrong with it.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at test.AddressBook.main(AddressBook.java:255)
```

Codes

```
public class AddressBook 
{
static Scanner inFile;
static FileWriter outFile;
static ArrayList<extPerson> person;
static extPerson record;
static File fileName = new File("AddressBook.txt");
private boolean b;
```

Here's the codes for Main.

```
public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException
{   
    int option = 0;
    int n = 0;
    AddressBook ab = new AddressBook();


    inFile = new Scanner(new FileReader(fileName)).useDelimiter("[|\\n]");
    //System.out.println(inFile.delimiter());
    //int count = 0;
    while(inFile.hasNext())
    {

        String fName = inFile.next();
        //System.out.print(fName);

        String mName = inFile.next();
        //System.out.print(mName);

        String lName = inFile.next();
        //System.out.print(lName);

        int phone = inFile.nextInt();
        //System.out.println(phone);

        String relationship = inFile.next();
        //System.out.print(relationship);

        int day = inFile.nextInt();
        //System.out.print(day);

        int month  = inFile.nextInt();
        //System.out.print(month);

        int year  = inFile.nextInt();
        //System.out.print(year);

        String street = inFile.next();
        //System.out.print(street);

        String city = inFile.next();
        //System.out.print(city);

        String state = inFile.next();
        //System.out.print(state);

        String zipCode = inFile.next();
        //System.out.println(zipCode);

        record = new extPerson(fName, mName, lName, phone, relationship, 
                day, month, year, street, city, state, zipCode);
        person.add(record);

    }


    while (true)
    {
        String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                            "Please Enter a number indicating your choice of action:"
                            + "\nEnter 1 To Add Record"
                            + "\nEnter 2 To Search Record By Last Name"
                            + "\nEnter 3 To Delete Record"
                            + "\nEnter 4 To Modify Record"
                            + "\nEnter 5 To Display All Records"
                            + "\nEnter 6 To Exit");

        if((input != null)&&(input.isEmpty() != true))
        {
            option = Integer.parseInt(input);

             if((option > 0 ) && (option < 7))
            {
                switch (option) {

                case 1:
                   ab.addRecord();
                   break;

                case 2:
                   ab.searchRecord();
                   break;

                case 3:
                   ab.deleteRecord();
                   break;

                case 4:

                    ab.modifyRecord();
                    break;

                case 5:

                    ab.allRecord();
                    break;

                case 6:
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
            else if(option == JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION)
            {
                n = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Are you sure you want to close?");
                if(n == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
                    System.exit(0);

            }

        }

        else if (input == null)
        {

            n = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Are you sure you want to close?",
                    "Confirm",
                    JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
            if(n == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
                System.exit(0);

        }
        else 
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid option. Please try again.");
        }


    }
}
```

I just need someone to point me to the right direction and possibly explain to me what's causing this Exception. Any help would be greatly appreciated. If you need more codes to analyse the problem, let me know and I'll post it up. Thanks again.

EDIT Sample data

```
Jeremy|Ronald|Wright|4331732|Family Member|06|04|2013|Eastlawn|Orange Cove|Texas|06666-9139
Heather|Paula|Perkins|7285248|Friends|04|06|2013|Bashford|Yuba City|New Mexico|99585-6820
Edward|Stephen|Allen|7186971|Family Member|25|06|2013|Reinke|Downey|Arizona|15915-9508
Dorothy|Philip|Robinson|8932173|Business Associate|15|07|2013|Harper|La Verne|Montana|37275-3957
Joan|Harry|Wilson|3859088|Business Associate|01|02|2014|Eastlawn|Antioch|Maryland|85923
```

Comment: Can you post your sample data? The error just means that it encountered a type which didn't match what you were expecting. In this case I imagine it found a string when it was expecting an integer. If I had to guess, I would say that your file looks like: _FirstName_`|\n`_MiddleName_`|\n`_LastName_`|\n`_SomeUnexpectedString_`|\n`_RemainingData_

Comment: ...or a phone number that cannot be parsed as an `int` (say, a phone number which, converted to `int`, would be larger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`)

Comment: I've posted the sample data. That's what's confusing me, on the data, phone is an int.

Comment: If you remove the first 4 print statements in `main()`, what gets printed before the failure?

Comment: @Mithfindel makes a great point, and although it doesn't look like this is your specific problem, it would probably make more sense to read in the phone number as a string, since you never need to perform mathematical operations on it. :)

Comment: Given your sample data, you should have a go at OpenCSV instead

Comment: @Jamey If I remove from main, data file or both? 
If I remove both, it just throws another Exception apparently.

If I convert it to a string, it runs fine. LOL.
But why is that so? What made the program throw that exception out of nowhere?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I meant if you uncomment these lines: `//System.out.print(fName);` `//System.out.print(mName);` `//System.out.print(lName);` `//System.out.print(phone);` Not sure why I said remove. :)

Comment: @Jamey Yup it gives another Exception. but in `int day = inFile.nextInt()` now.

Comment: @fge I'll check OpenCSV out. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Is it possible that its a software issue? Cache is full or what not? just guessing.

Answer (score 1):

Reading line by line splitting, and parsing will help to avoid these kind of problems.

```
    while (inFile.hasNext()) {
        String line = inFile.nextLine();
        String[] tokens = line.split("\\|");
        String fName = tokens[0];
        String mName = tokens[1];
        String lName = tokens[2];
        int phone = Integer.parseInt(tokens[3]);
        String relationship = tokens[4];
        int day = Integer.parseInt(tokens[5]);
        int month = Integer.parseInt(tokens[6]);
        int year = Integer.parseInt(tokens[7]);
        String street = tokens[8];
        String city = tokens[9];
        String state = tokens[10];
        String zipCode = tokens[11];
    }
```

Doing this with your text file snippet works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

In Java some delimiter splitters use null/empty tokens others not.
If you have `||` or `|notInt|` and  it falls that `scanner.nextInt()` is run you will get an **ImputMissmatchException**

```
Scanner i =
        new Scanner("Jeremy|Ronald|Wright|43|||Family Member|06|04|2013|06666-9139\n").useDelimiter("[|\\n]");
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            System.out.println(i.next());
        }
        for (int j = 3; j < 6; j++) {
            int loc = i.nextInt();   // here i get same exception  
                                     // when reading next int after 43
            System.out.println(loc);
        }
    }
```

Scanner with Delimiter and string splitter process empty tokens, while StringTokenizer doesn't, running the below code

```
    System.out.println("------Scanner Delimiter------------------------------");
    Scanner i =
        new Scanner("Jeremy|Ronald|433|||06|04|2013|06666-9139").useDelimiter("[|]");
    while (i.hasNext()) {           
            System.out.println("\""+i.next()+"\"");         
    }
    System.out.println("---------------String split---------------------");

     String[] result = "Jeremy|Ronald|433|||06|04|2013|06666-9139".split("[|]");
     for(String s: result)
         System.out.println("\""+s+"\"");

    System.out.println("-------------String Tokenizer-----------------------");

     StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer("Jeremy|Ronald|433|||06|04|2013|06666-9139", "|");
     while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
         System.out.println("\""+st.nextToken()+"\"");
     }
```

Will output:

`------Scanner Delimiter------------------------------
"Jeremy"
"Ronald"
"433"
""
""
"06"
"04"
"2013"
"06666-9139"
---------------String split---------------------
"Jeremy"
"Ronald"
"433"
""
""
"06"
"04"
"2013"
"06666-9139"
-------------String Tokenizer-----------------------
"Jeremy"
"Ronald"
"433"
"06"
"04"
"2013"
"06666-9139"`